# Change sql to linq

Tags: linq

hi could anyone advice how to change the following sql script to linq?

`SELECT *, CASE WHEN  datepart(day, DateIssue)<27 THEN datepart(month,DateIssue) 
ELSE datepart(month,DateIssue) % 12 + 1 END as group_name 
FROM Payments;`

thanks

Comment: Hi i am actually refer to this thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922231/grouping-data-by-date-ranges) which Ovidiu Pacurar posted the sql script instead of linq. i have tried using his script and it works so i wonder anyone else has any idea changing that to linq. thanks

Comment: You'll enjoy LINQ once you learn how to use it. I strongly suggest that you sit down with a good tutorial (or even [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx)) and really learn how LINQ works. Asking for others to convert expressions one by one is not a path to mastery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a list of payments called `Payments`:

```
var query = from p in Payments
            let dateIssue = (DateTime)p["DateIssue"]
            let gName = (dateIssue.Day < 27) ? (dateIssue.Month) : (dateIssue.Month % 12 + 1)
            select new { payment = p, groupName = gName };
```

The `Payments` list can be anything that derives from Iterable

if needed you can iterate that this way:

```
foreach (var value in query) {
     // value.payment the original item of Payments
     // and value.groupName contains the other column
}
```

God bless!

Comment: I just saw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922231/grouping-data-by-date-ranges . What I wrote is not what you want, you should group p by gName ... see (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336754.aspx#simple1)