# Multiple Group data

Tags: linq

I have a set of data as below from my `Payment` table

```
DateIssue             | Amount | CoursePaidForMonth | 
  2/3/2011 9:54:07 PM | 2000.00|          2
 2/27/2011 2:22:58 PM |   80.00|          2
 3/5/2011 11:14:56 PM |   80.00|          3
 3/27/2011 2:22:58 PM |   80.00|          2
 2/8/2011 6:32:45 PM  |   80.00|          2
```

I would like to perform two sets of grouping for the data above:

1. The closing date is on the 27 of every month, so I would like to group all the data from 27 till 26 of next month into a group. This is done successfully from the `gName`. NO PROBLEM !! Check out the output as the image below.

   ```
   DateIssue             AppendCommToMonthΞΞ CoursePaidForMonthΞΞ TotalAmountΞΞ 
   2/8/2011 6:32:45 PM            2                    2             2080.00
   2/27/2011 2:22:58 PM           3                    2              160.00
   3/27/2011 2:22:58 PM           4                    2               80.00
   ```
2. Now I would like to perform another grouping on the same query. I would like to group the `CoursePaidForMonth` as well. Meaning to say, the final output should show 4 lines of records instead of just 3, it group by from 27 this month till 26 of next month into a group and also by `CoursePaidForMonth`. How to do this?

   ```
   DateIssue             AppendCommToMonthΞΞ CoursePaidForMonthΞΞ TotalAmountΞΞ 
   2/8/2011 6:32:45 PM            2                    2             2080.00
   2/27/2011 2:22:58 PM           3                    2              80.00
   3/5/2011 11:14:56 PM           3                    3              80.00
   3/27/2011 2:22:58 PM           4                    2              80.00
   ```

My code is here:

```
var result = from p in db.Payments
               join soi in db.SaleOrderItems on p.ReferenceId equals soi.Id
               join ct in db.CourseByTutors on soi.InventoryOrCourseId equals ct.CourseId                              
               where p.PayType == (int)PayTypes.PayCourseFee
               && ct.TutorId == tutorId
               let gName = (p.DateIssue.Value.Day < 27) ? (p.DateIssue.Value.Month) : (p.DateIssue.Value.Month % 12 + 1)
               group p by new { gName} into g
               select new
               {
                  DateIssue = g.Select(x => x.DateIssue).First(),
                  AppendCommForWhichMonth = g.Key.gName,
                  CoursePaidForMonth = g.Select(x => x.CoursePaidForMonth).First(),
                                 TotalAmount = g.Sum(x => x.Amount),
               };
```

Please advice..

Comment: hi please inform me if my question does not make sense to u

Comment: i have edited the question. HOpe it makes more sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the `CoursePaidForMonth` into your key.  Something like this:

```
var query = from p in db.Payments
            join soi in db.SaleOrderItems
                on p.ReferenceId equals soi.Id
            join cbt in db.CourseByTutors
                on soi.InventoryOrCourseId equals cbt.CourseId
            where p.PayType == (int)PayTypes.PayCourseFee && cbt.TutorId == tutorId
            orderby p.DateIssue
            let AppendCommForWhichMonth = p.DateIssue.Month + p.DateIssue.Day < 27 ? 0 : 1
            group p
                by new { AppendCommForWhichMonth, p.CoursePaidForMonth }
                into g
            select new
            {
                g.First().DateIssue,
                g.Key.AppendCommForWhichMonth,
                g.Key.CoursePaidForMonth,
                TotalAmount = g.Sum(p => p.Amount),
            };
```

Comment: I've made some tweaks to the query.  I don't think it would negatively affect the results.  You can change it back if you want.  I ordered it to ensure that the earliest date is chosen.  The `% 12` part seemed unnecessary to me.  The months already are in the interval, [0,12).  Unless I've misunderstood and it is not that way in the database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i tried your code but it said that the DateIssue at g.First().DateIssue,  "'System.Nullable<decimal>' does not contain a definition for 'DateIssue' and no extension method 'DateIssue' accepting a first argument of type " and also "The name 'TotalAmount' does not exist in the current context" Should i include those 2 into the group by new{} ?

Comment: @belinq: What I originally had was incorrect.  I changed what was being grouped but forgot I couldn't do that for this query.  Try the new code again.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful reply. It successful do the 2 grouping. But it shows only 3 rows of records. DateIssue AppendCommForWhichMonthΞΞ CoursePaidForMonthΞΞ 
2/3/2011 9:54:07 PM
 0
 2
 2080.00
 <br>    
2/27/2011 2:22:58 PM
 1
 2
 160.00
 <br>    
3/5/2011 11:14:56 PM
 0
 3
 80.00

Comment: if i were to change your query to this ..then it works.      let dateissue = (DateTime)p.DateIssue
    let AppendCommForWhichMonth = (dateissue.Day < 27) ?(dateissue.Month):(dateissue.Month % 12 + 1)

Comment: @belinq: My tests with the above data and query yielded 4 rows that matched your example output.  I guess I was mistaken about the modulo arithmetic earlier.  But at least you've got it working now and that's what matters.